# Detect automatically if the server runs on IPv4 or on IPv6

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ipv6, ipv4

I am developing a python3 client to connect to a UDP server that randomly alternates between 2 states: accepting only IPv4 packets and IPv6 packets. How can I create a socket that I can use to send a message using either type of of IP version so that it successfully sends the message.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I suspect it would be easier to just fix the server.

Comment: I don't have control over the server unfortunately.I am able to send it a message by repeating in a loop until there is a match between my socket and the server's state. I just want to make it more efficient.

Comment: Ouch, that is a horrible server implementation. Good luck solving this.